# Google chrome crashes when you paste from a remote session

Tags: google-chrome

I often have a remote desktop session or a java remoting tool up and whenever i copy from within a remote session and paste into chrome browser, the browser freezes and i have to kill it for anything to work again.

has anyone seen this or have a resolution?

i have to remember to copy and paste into notepad first and then copy from notepad and then into chrome which is a pain.

I am using google chrome 5.0

Comment: What operating system and remote desktop client are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there already exists a (similar) bug on this on [Google Chrome bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12312), but has been marked as invalid. Might be worthwhile to [file a new bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), if you can reproduce it all the time.
Related: [Bug reporting guidelines](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)